# Accessing Password Protected Jenkins Maven Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

So our company uses Jenkins, with the Maven repository plugin. Our Jenkins requires a signin to access any of it's pages.

So I setup my settings.xml file with the repository name (set in my POM.xml), my username for the Jenkins, and my password (encrypted in the maven command prompt). I then refreshed my settings.xml file in m2e, as well as made sure the path was correct. I refreshed all of my dependancies, but I still get:

```
Error code 403, Forbidden
```

When I attempt to compile.

Is there something that I am forgetting? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Error code 401 indicates an authentication/authorization problem. 403 ("forbidden") suggests you're accessing an invalid URL. Run Maven in debug mode and attempt to debug the URLs being used.

Comment: The URL is correct, that is definitely not the issue.

Comment: Asking an obvious question... You're not publishing artifacts to Jenkins are you? That is not supported.... Personally I run a separate instance of Nexus to host my release binaries. I also publish build logs into Nexus, so this setup means I have no strong backup requirements for my Jenkins server.

Comment: We're considering putting a Nexus up. As well, no. Just trying to use the Maven Repository plugin.